# Get Category posts in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get posts under their category name. I tried lots of tutorials on the web none of them works for me!

This is my Controller:

```
public function showcoursecat($slug) {
    $coursecateories = course::with('coursecateory')
        ->where('slug', $slug)
        ->get();

    return view ('frontend.coursecats', compact('coursecateories'));
}
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/courses/cat/{slug}', 'FrontendController@showcoursecat')
    ->name('coursecat')
    ->where('slug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
```

My Course model:

```
class Course extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = "Courses";

    protected $fillable = [
        'course_name', 
        'course_description', 
        'course_price', 
        'course_disscount',  
        'slug', 
        'image', 
        'category_id', 
        'user_id', 
        'approve',
    ];

    protected $events = [
        'created' => Events\CourseApproved::class,
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function coursecateories() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Coursecateory::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

My Coursecateory model:

```
class Coursecateory extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        'image', 
        'slug',
    ];

    public function courses() {
        return $this->hasMany(Course::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

And here is my view:

```
@foreach($coursecateories as $coursecateory)

    <h3>{{ $coursecateory->course_name }}</h3>

    @foreach($coursecateory->courses as $course)

        <h4><a href="#">{{ $course->course_name }}</a></h4>

        <p>{{ $course->course_description }}</p>

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: Is your question actually, "I want to get courses under their category name"?

Comment: @haakym courses are kind of posts just different post_type. Is your answer actually?

Comment: Is the slag for cat or for course ??

Comment: @Maraboc for cat's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The you should do it like this :

```
$coursecateories = Coursecateory::with('courses')->where('slug', $slug)->get();
```

And in the view i think you mean `<h3>{{ $coursecateory->name }}</h3>` not `<h3>{{ $coursecateory->course_name }}</h3>`:

```
@foreach($coursecateories as $coursecateory)

    <h3>{{ $coursecateory->name }}</h3>

    @foreach($coursecateory->courses as $course)

        <h4><a href="#">{{ $course->course_name }}</a></h4>
        <p>{{ $course->course_description }}</p>

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

**UPDATE**

According to the need of the pagination from the comments you can do it like so :

```
$category = Coursecateory::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$courses = $category->courses()->paginate(10);
return view('frontend.coursecats', compact('category', 'courses'));
```

And in the view :

```
<h3>{{ $category->name }}</h3>
@foreach($courses as $course)

    <h4><a href="#">{{ $course->course_name }}</a></h4>
    <p>{{ $course->course_description }}</p>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Do you know why if i use `->paginate(10);` instead of `get();` not working on this?

Comment: may be you have less than 10 categories !!

Comment: how many categories that you have with the same slug ? if it's only one then there is no need for the pagination !

Comment: is one! but is about courses under each category i want to paginate them. example if i open `laravel` category and it has 100 courses under it, i want to be paginate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150801/discussion-between-maraboc-and-robert-nicjoo).